# Fill tool freezes QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I am trying to figure out a way to create a stream order file with the Horton method, however seeing as Arcmap only does either Strahler or Shreve, this isn't ideal. I opted to try QGIS, however it cannot apply the Fill sinks algorithm on the World 30 DEM over the state of catarina (or even a smaller sized region). I've disabled all unnecessary plugins and only have "Processing" enabled. It constantly freezes. I figured it was simply loading however after a night of "working", it has failed to display the information.

Comment: It could be because there's a lot of data which forces QGIS to _hang_ sometimes. If you installed QGIS using the OSGeo4W installer, you could consider running the _Fill Sinks_ tool **outside** of QGIS. This would allocate more memory and processing resources to the tool itself instead of all of QGIS.